# Unable to execute java code in Linux server

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

I have made one java API service. While Calling this service I am trying to get response from Dialogue flow. Now When I am executing the code on window platform then It is working fine.But when I am publish it ,on Linux server. And trying to test it Giving error.

I have done it with export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]" on system variable.Even I have setup the path on Linux server but it is not working.Then I have put .json file on project and trying to read and then Again making call. (These things are working fine only on local system not Linux after publish the project)

````
List<String> texts= new ArrayList<String>();
texts.add("Hi");
String sessionId="3f46dfa4-5204-84f3-1488-5556f3d6b8a1";
String languageCode="en-US";
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("E:\\GoogleDialogFlow\\ChatBox\\Json.json"))
.createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));

SessionsSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = SessionsSettings.newBuilder();
SessionsSettings sessionsSettings = settingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build();
SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings);
SessionName session = SessionName.of(projectId, sessionId);
com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.TextInput.Builder textInput = TextInput.newBuilder().setText("Hi").setLanguageCode(languageCode);
QueryInput queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder().setText(textInput).build();
DetectIntentResponse response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput);
QueryResult queryResult = response.getQueryResult();
System.out.println("====================");
System.out.format("Query Text: '%s'\n", queryResult.getQueryText());
System.out.format("Detected Intent: %s (confidence: %f)\n",
queryResult.getIntent().getDisplayName(), queryResult.getIntentDetectionConfidence());
System.out.format("Fulfillment Text: '%s'\n", queryResult.getFulfillmentText());    
credentials.toBuilder().build();```
````

Comment: Your linux system does not have "E:\\GoogleDialogFlow\\ChatBox\\Json.json". You will need to find a way to use that file without storing it on a Windows local drive. There are multiple solutions; but using ``E:\`` is not one of them.

Comment: Nope. I am saving .json file on Tomcat server .There I am making call.Such as App/Tomcat/Lib/  like that

Comment: Where in the tomcat did you put the json file? You have to put the file inside ROOT folder

Comment: are you talking about GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, I has setup those on root but it was not working .so I have saved them in one location then trying to read and generate